# Easiest Way to Convert Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VirtualBox VM (VDI) to TrueCrypt VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, truecrypt

I have an existing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VirtualBox VM (VDI) that I would like to convert to full disc encryption using TrueCrypt. My only experience with TrueCrypt comes from a fresh Ubuntu install, or encrypting just a home directory, and reading the ubuntuforums.org posts on this subject haven't been very helpful.

I would hope there is a way to avoid creating a new Ubuntu full disc encryption installation, mounting my unencrypted partion from my encrypted one, and copying everything over (possibly from a third OS.)

Thanks for looking at my question,

-Brian J. Stinar-